# Validation based on previous step

Tags: django, django-formwizard

Say I have an input on one step and another input on the next step (I am using SessionWizardView). I need to validate next step input is identical to input from previous step. It would be great to update validator on the go to show correct errors if inputs are not identical with input from previos step because I am using ajax validation that executes django form validators before submit.

I thought about getting session with ThreadLocal.get_current_request() in second step input validator and compare it somehow. But i dont think it is a good solution :) Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not just put the input from the previous step in the `context` and compare it in the next step before submit on the next one ?

Comment: You mean get context with get_context_data()? Probably but how can I compare in the next step? And the main idea - to modify form validator somehow to show correct errors?

Comment: On submit of step 1, you will have the value. What i m saying is, add this as a context variable to step 2. That way, You can easily compare while submitting step 2 if the values are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should do it:

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
        kwargs = {}
        if step == 'second_step':
            cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('first_step')
            kwargs.update({'first_input': cleaned_data['first_input'] })

        return kwargs
```

then you pop it in your second form

```
class SecondForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.first_input = kwargs.pop('first_input', None)
        super(SecondForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super(SecondForm, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        # compare self.first_input with self.cleaned_data['second_input']

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Actualy i was able to get data from first_step through ` self.storage.get_step_data`. method `get_cleaned_data_for_step` returns None because somehow method `get_form` inside it returns class instead of instance. Or I have missed something?

Comment: @Oink You're right, the storage.get_step_data is perfect for simple case (it takes validated raw data). I'm kinda surprised you have an issue with get_cleaned_data_for_step. I can't help with that since I don't see the code. Just go with get_step_data now, if you get into more complicated wizard process then help yourself with my solution :)